# upload a file and then ftp it to another server with PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I generated a text file on server1, and then I need to FTP it to server3.

Due to firewall, I could not FTP it directly but have to go through server2.

I want server1 to call PHP script on server2 and then pass the text file to server3.
Any idea how can I start with the PHP script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is going to help. Use curl to call the script on server 2. Then, form server2 you can ftp to server3. curl supports [post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP))-ing a lot data, so you should be fine. Not sure if it's the best solution, but it might get the job done.